# Applied clinical research clinical trials and regulatory affairs

Tags: journals, impact-factor, india

Is this journal a legitimate one with impact factor or is it a fraud?

Answer (score 0):

This journal is not indexed in any reputable database, or at least i couldn't find it. It has no Impact factor according to the updated listed shared by thomson and reuter.

Before submitting my manuscript i will alyways check if the journal i am targeting is indexed in a reputable database like scopus, web of sciences and etc.

And you should also check the publishing house/company that journal belongs to, check other journals belong to that publishing house.